# Maven shade two executions with different log4j.properties

Tags: java, maven, log4j, pom.xml, maven-shade-plugin

I have a module that creates two jars based on two shade executions. I want each of them to bundle different log4j.properties files in the jar. I have the following transformer each of the executions in my pom.xml:

```
<transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.IncludeResourceTransformer">
<resource>log4j.properties</resource>
<file>log4j-ONE.properties</file>
</transformer>
```

What I end up with is both log4j files in both of my jars and none using it. Is it possible to configure the transformer so that each of the executions only includes the relevant log4j-xxx.properties file (renamed to log4j.properties so that log4j uses it)?

The end goal is to have each of the jars write to different log files, I can't figure out an easier way to do it.

Comment: longshot guess....  but resource tag starts from package root ( the root of your jar file... the target folder ecc) file starts from the root of your maven project. So if you have placed the log4j-ONE.properties in a resource folder should explain the behavior

Comment: Yes, that fixed it, thank you.

Comment: nice! please check the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Resource** tag in shade plugin configuration starts searching for content from *package root* ( the root of your jar file... the target folder ecc) and **file** tag starts from the root of your maven project. So if you have placed the log4j-ONE.properties in a resource folder should explain the behavior.